# Excel how to check if a row has any other values and return the index

Tags: excel

I have this big table where the first column is the person. The second column is something they all have. And then there are different columns for possible other things they could have.

For example :

```
Person  apples  pears   bananas oranges
Luc 7   0   0   0
Julia   10  0   0   2
Maria   8   0   0   0
Lena    15  0   3   0
Tina    2   1   0   1
```

I know for  a fact that everybody eats apples, but i would like to know if people eat other things also and wich thing those are
The result should be

```
Person  appels  pears   bananas oranges result
Luc 7   0   0   0   0
Julia   10  0   0   2   oranges
Maria   8   0   0   0   0
Lena    15  0   3   0   bananas
Tina    2   1   0   1   pears, oranges
```

The last column doesn't have to be the name of the fruit, I would be happy if I had the column number. I tried `HLOOKUP`, but this doesn't work . Or maybe I don't use the right lookup_value ? I use `> 0` as `lookup_value`.

Can somebody please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution: Create "dummy variables" (formatted with text instead of `{0,1}` values) that are only populated for fruits actually consumed (`N>0`), and then concatenate in the results column:

```
ID       Apples     Pears     Bananas     Oranges     d_apples     d_pears     d_bananas     d_oranges     result
Luc      7          0         0           0           Apples                                               
Julia    10         0         0           2           Apples                                 Oranges       Oranges
Maria    8          0         0           0           Apples                                               
Lena     15         0         3           0           Apples                    Bananas                    Bananas
Tina     2          1         0           1           Apples       Pears                     Oranges       Pears Oranges
```

In the `d_apples` column, I've entered `=IF(B2>0, B$1, "")` and filled this across the `d_` columns.
In the `results` column, I've entered `=TRIM(CONCATENATE(G2, " ", H2, " ", I2))`.

The `TRIM()` function removes the extra blank spaces between words for fruits not eaten. Note of course that this doesn't add commas between words, and adding commas to the `CONCATENATE()` function will yield something like `, Bananas,`.

If you want the column numbers, you can change `B$1` in the `IF()` function to `COLUMN(B$1)`.